# Creating a new columns in pandas based on the structure of the other

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of data that looks like this:

```
F    M

f1   m1
f1   m2
f1   m3
f2   m1
f3   m1
f3   m2
```

and I need to add the third column made of objects of type `str`. So the table should look like so:

```
F    M   B

f1   m1  'b1'
f1   m2  'b2'
f1   m3  'b3'
f2   m1  'b1'
f3   m1  'b1'
f3   m2  'b2'
```

What would be the right way to do this in pandas? There are similar questions but I couldn't find a similar task and I can't figure out how to construct this B column.

**EDIT**:

Sorry for not being clear enough. All the values in the table (f{i} and m{i}) are some strings.

Comment: So you just want to replace letter `m` with letter `b`?

Comment: @Psidom oh no, sorry I was not quite clear. The values in the F column are strings, the same regards the M column. And the B column should look like so. All of those f{i} and m{i} are some strings.

Comment: What is the logic then? row numbers group by column `F` preceded by a letter `b`?

Comment: @Psidom The logic is as follows: three ms correspond to f1, one m corresponds to f2 and two  ms correspond to f3. All m{i} are different for f{i}, that's, m1 for f1 is different from m1 for f2 etc. And the B column should look like it does.

Comment: @Foobard Is my answer what you're looking for? If not, I'll delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupby.cumcount` which essentially gives the row number for each *F*, and then you can concatenate the row number with a letter such as `b`:

```
df['B'] = 'b'+df.groupby('F').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

df
#    F   M   B
#0  f1  m1  b1
#1  f1  m2  b2
#2  f1  m3  b3
#3  f2  m1  b1
#4  f3  m1  b1
#5  f3  m2  b2
```

Comment: ooh seems like that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you ever so much.

Comment: Sure. Glad it helps!

Comment: I knew I have to group by F, but I couldn't figure out how to increment b's index. Perfect!